# V-FOR with background images

Tags: vue.js, v-for, vue-props

I'm trying to get a v-for cycle with background images. My intention is to have for columns each containing a different background image. Is there something wrong here? :(
Please note also photos it's an array imported with props. This is a component template.

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div
      v-for="photo in photos"
      :key="photo"
      class="col-3"
      style="background-image: url({{photo.url}})"
    >
      Need to see photo here
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["photos"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use template literals with the `:style` shorthand for `v-bind:style`

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div
      v-for="(photo, index) in photos"
      :key="index"
      class="col-3"
      :style="`background-image: url(${photo.url})`"
    >
      Need to see photo here
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Binding Inline Styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)

```
    <div
      v-for="photo in photos"
      :key="photo"
      class="col-3"
      v-bind:style="{background-image:  'url(' + photo.url + ')'}"
    >
      Need to see photo here
    </div>
```